# Select every query from a set which results contain a record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, search, model, ransack

I'm working on a Rails 6.1 app that has these two models:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: publications
#
#  allow_comments        :boolean          default(FALSE)
#  created_at            :datetime         not null
#  draft                 :boolean          default(FALSE)
#  filter_query          :jsonb
#  id                    :integer          not null, primary key
#  content               :text             not null
#  user_id               :integer          not null
#  title                 :string
#  updated_at            :datetime         not null


# == Schema Information

#
# Table name: users
#  id                    :integer          not null, primary key
#  first_name            :string           not null
#  last_name             :string           not null
#  role_id               :integer          not null
#  some_other_associated_ids
```

Where the `publications.filter_query` field stores [Ransack](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack) query parameters. Those are used by the gem to create SQL queries and get users. The idea behind it is to limit which users can see a publication. These filters can include almost every field in the users table, and many fields on associated models. Also, those filters include equality, string containment, and ILIKE conditions. (We use PostgreSQL)

It is usually very easy to make any publication's query and get the users that can see that publication, but the inverse problem, getting which publications can a given user see, is a problem we have not managed to solve efficiently.

Currently, we UNION ALL the results of every query stored in every publication and filter using the user_id. But this solution takes a long time and consumes a lot of memory. With many publications, it has even triggered our puma web server to kill a worker.

I've been trying to google some solutions, but I'm finding difficult to formulate the problem correctly, and I can't find a better method.

How would you solve that problem? Any ideas are very welcomed.

I tried grouping the queries that matched on some fields, but the amount of possible combinations of filter made this impractical and prone to errors, while taking almost the same time.

I also tried to thread the process, taking a small number of publications and running their queries, later aggregating the results. This kind of worked, but consumed way too many database connections.